# Android connect Node.js REST unexpeceed end of stream

Tags: android, node.js, rest, httpurlconnection

I have setup a simple Node.js local server with express that returns a json like this

```
    router.get('/addUser', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('{ "result" : "FAILED", "error" : "TEST" }');
});
```

`Node.js` listens to localhost port 3000, so when connect to `localhost:3000/addUser` I expect to get back this json `{ "result" : "FAILED", "error" : "TEST" }`

When I try to call the above url from Android Emulator to `10.0.2.2:3000` (Android IP for localhost) with `HttpURLConnection` I get an exception `:*java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{10.0.2.2:3000, proxy=DIRECT@ hostAddress=10.0.2.2 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0).*`

When using a browser or postman to test my node.js server at 
http://localhost:3000/addUser it returns the json object correctly.

When I try to communicate from Android to a local Apache Server to a page returning the same json it works correctly.

Something goes wrong when conenecting from Android emulator to local Node.js server.

Comment: What ip do you bind express to? 0.0.0.0?

Comment: I have var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(3000);

Answer (score 3):

Finally the problem was caused by a space in querystring.  Browser and Postman seem to detect and automatically correct this error.

Comment: I also have this problem. got solved by using **trim()** function in **variables** used in **URL**.